# What is the size limit of picture to use free storage on Blogspot?

Tags: blogger

I've heard that the small pictures on Blogspot are not using Picassa storage limit, but are free to store. So I can post as much pictures as I want, even the whole photo archive, as long as I keep them small.

However, I've failed to find detailed information? Is it really true, and if so, what is the picture size limit (width, height, size in kB)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true. If you have a Google+ account, any image that is 2048 x 2048 pixels or smaller will not count against your total storage limit. If you do not have a Google+ account, any image that is 800 x 800 pixels or smaller will not count.

Reference: http://support.google.com/picasa/answer/1224181?hl=en